# Can you change chart.js radar chart axis to be logarithm?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, radar-chart

I have some data that varies a lot, i.e., some data are hundreds of times larger than others, I want to show them in logarithm so it looks better. But reading chart.js [document](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart), I can't find a way to do that.